# (Excel) If a value in a column matches given value return entire row

Tags: microsoft-excel

In sheet 1 I have data from every single NBA game in a season. Column D contains the teams name that played the game.

In sheet 2 I want to input a teams name and get all rows (from sheet 1) that match the team I entered.

How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Step 1: Do some research.

Comment: To elaborate on the comment from @Scott look into Index & Match functions.

Comment: Better share some sample data, since you wrote Team Name are in Col D (what I guess is the middle Cell value) if data Range is `A2:F10` like.

Comment: Exactly what is in col D?  Both teams or a single team?  If both, how are they separated?  How about a screenshot?

Comment: Please provide a sample about your problem first, THANKS.

Comment: Also, show what the result should look like.  Please note the Super User isn't intended as a "write me code" site, but people will help you solve a specific problem if you attempt to do it yourself.  Show what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Entire rows, that can be in any number, cann't be extracted through a formula.

Using Countif() you will get how many times that team is appearing in the first sheet, then it will be a different task to extract all rows from first sheet and put each column at proper place in Sheet B.

What you are saying doesn't even need Sheet B.

In the first Sheet itself, you select entire top heading, and click on Menu - Data - Filter.

That will put a filter on you data.

Then, the column in which your team name is there, you click on filter (the funnel icon at the end of the header name) and put a team's name and press enter.

All the rows of only that team will show up, and all rows in which that team was not there will be hidden.